# Spark streaming multiple Kafka topic to multiple Database table with checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, checkpoint

I'm building spark streaming from Apache Kafka to our columnar DataBase.

To ensure fault tolerance I'm using HDFS checkpoint and write ahead log.

Apache Kafka topic -> spark streaming -> HDFS checkpoint->  spark SQl ( for messages manipulation)-> spark  jdbc for  our Db.

When  I'm using spark jobs for one topic and table everything is working file.

I'm trying to stream  in one  spark  job multiple Kafka topics and to write for multiple tables in here started  the problem  with the checkpoint ( which  is per one  topic table )

The **problem** is with **checkpoints** :(

1) If I will use "KafkaUtils.createDirectStream"  with a list of topics and  "groupBy" topic  name **but** the checkpoint folder is one and if, for example, I will need to increase resources during the ongoing streaming (change amount of cors due  to Kafka  Lag)  this will be impossible because today it's possible only if I delete  the checkpoint folder and restart  the spark  job.

2) Use multiple spark streamingContext this I will try today and see if it works.

3) Multiple sparkStreaming  with high-level consumers ( offset  saved  in kafka10...)

Any other ideas/solutions that I'm missing 
Does structure streams with multiple Kafka topics and checkpoints behave differently?

Thx

Comment: Why do you use Spark Streaming not [Spark Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)?

Comment: Do you know if Spark Structured Streaming handle differently when using multiple Kafka topics and checkpoint paths?

Comment: Structured Streaming handles checkpointing for you and avoids the serialization issue you're referring to. As long as you don't change your aggregation query you can stop and restart your query as needed.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I saw in your book and example for structured stream multiple topics, how can extend it to multiple outputs ( JDBC tables).            If I will use multiple streams ( one per topic) with a query.start() for each one save to different table then they will not run in parallel. Does structured stream, not batch, can run in parallel. Thx :)